# App crashing on click of home button of iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad

In my iPhone application, I have an UIWebView where I load data from an xml file, after loading it if I press my iPhones home button and if I try to reopen my app its loading then after that if I click back button and load webview again and then click home button try to reopen app is not at all launching, its getting crashed. In my organiser the crash report is like this :

```
libSystem.B.dylib               0x33c30176 cache_remove_with_block + 18
1   CoreFoundation                  0x33ad9e52 __NSCacheApplicationDidEnterBackgroundCallBack + 18
2   CoreFoundation                  0x33a779a4 __cfnote_callback + 20
3   CoreFoundation                  0x33a4711c __CFXNotificationPost_old + 396
4   CoreFoundation                  0x33a46dbc _CFXNotificationPostNotification + 112
5   Foundation                      0x3361cd1c -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 64
6   UIKit                           0x320c1752 -[UIApplication _handleApplicationSuspend:eventInfo:] + 494
7   UIKit                           0x320667a6 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1910
8   UIKit                           0x32065ec2 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 38
9   UIKit                           0x32065900 _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 5084
10  GraphicsServices                0x33b0eefc PurpleEventCallback + 660
11  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 20
12  CoreFoundation                  0x33a556bc __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 160
13  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47f76 __CFRunLoopRun + 514
14  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47c80 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 224
15  CoreFoundation                  0x33a47b88 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 52
16  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e4a4 GSEventRunModal + 108
17  GraphicsServices                0x33b0e550 GSEventRun + 56
18  UIKit                           0x32099322 -[UIApplication _run] + 406
19  UIKit                           0x32096e8c UIApplicationMain + 664
```

how to resolve this? what may be the cause of this?
Any help is thankful in advance.

Comment: please, add some code, hard to see what's going on without

Comment: Do you have a delegate (or other observer) that handles `applicationWillResignActive:` / `UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification`?

Answer (score 0):

We had the same issue (on devices running iOS 4.x only btw..)
The cause of it has been the use of mutable objects in the cache. We put a NSMutableDictionary in the cache and and manipulated it afterwards. Then when the cache was released (to be deallocated) something seems to have happened that later crashed the app on suspend.

Hope this also solves your issue!

---

**Update:**

We found a solution thanks to [this dev forum entry](https://devforums.apple.com/message/421845#421845). It appears that `NSCache` prior to iOS 4.3 was not unregistering itself from the notification center.

We worked around this issue by creating a simple subclass of `NSCache` and implement the `-dealloc` method like so (ARC version):

```
- (void)dealloc;
{
    // NSCache had an issue on iOS prior to 4.3 where it didn't unregister from notifications and caused crashes
    // see https://devforums.apple.com/message/421845#421845
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Now use this class instead of `NSCache` and you should be okay. Fingers crossed. :)

Comment: seems like we're still running into this problem. so no good news :(

Comment: same here! have you guys found an answer??

Comment: @SeongHo Actually found a solution. Please check the updated Answer.